# How to serve blank image for inbound missing images?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I am having an issue where a number of images have been used by external sites and at present it is simply showing as images not being found. I would like to have these errors obviously in the logs, however I would also like to have Apache serve the requester with a 1x1 transparent pixel image instead of simply not finding it. How does one set this up?

Comment: Set the image as 404 `ErrorDocument`, limited to image resources via `<Files>`/`<FilesMatch>` directive. And btw., _redirecting_ to some XXX picture to punish hotlinkers is more fun ;-)

Comment: @CBroe Blue-waffle for hotlinkers... Ah, the high road...

Comment: @CBroe This is not funny, if these images will be seen by children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe already suggested, you can give any document as the [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) served to the client, even a transparent pixel image

```
ErrorDocument 404 /images/1x1.png
```

If you put the .htaccess in the `images` folder, only missing files from here and below will be treated.

The returned status code `404` will still be logged in the `access.log` together with the missing image filename.